# page specific wordpress content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to input a dashboard (simple html & css) above the page title on my wordpress site but only for the pages with the ID 777, 880 and 374.

I am assuming I need to make a function using is_page and then add that function to my page.php file but I can't seem to work it out.

Thanks for any help,
Scott

Comment: That is it working guys, it was a lot simpler than I realised. I am new here is there a way to mark this as solved?

Comment: You can answer yourself to the question. Or we can delete this question if you think the solution is not too useful for others.

Comment: I think this question is too simple, I would be fine with it being deleted. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could add logic like this to your page.php

```
<?php 
    if(is_page(777) || is_page(880) || is_page(374)) {
        // Special Page Content Goes Here...
    }
?>
```

** This will only work if the ID's are actually pages and not posts. Otherwise the conditional logic would be different.

Comment: Really the cleaner way yo do this would be create a page template, and assign that template to the pages with those id's https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Hold an array somewhere in your application with the allowed users (if just a few and not growing):

```
$allowedUsers = array('777' => true, '880' => true, '374' => true);

$userId = [current user id];
if($allowedUsers[$userId]) {
    // Display dashboard content
}
```

If you have a more advanced user management system you should instead have priviliges and/or roles set for each specific user.